# How to apply backpropagation to a single output neuron?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

I am making a neural network with reinforcement.

The model looks like this:
63 input neurons (environment state) - 21 neurons in the hidden layer - 4 outputs. The output neurons contain the probability of going up, down, left, right. ([0,0,0,1])

The neural network gives the result of the move, the agent performs an action.
Each new move, after the agent has performed actions, I give him a reward or a penalty.

How to do backpropagation in **tensor flow js?** I need not an error to propagate back, but a reward or a penalty. And only from a certain output neuron.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww7Cf.png)

Example:

1. The neural network predicted the move to the right
2. the agent went to the right and left the playing field.
3. This is a bad action. The agent is charged a fine of -0.02
4. In the current model of the neural network, we determine the output neuron that responds to the move to the right.
5. We backpropagate from this neuron back with a coefficient of -0.02. If it is not a fine, but a reward, then the coefficient will be positive.

How to do step 5 in code?

UDP:I initially thought that the task is simple and does not require additional clarification. Therefore, I formulated the question briefly. I think it's worth giving more information :) The game consists of 10 squares in width and 10 in height, a total of 100. There are 20 chicken legs in a static position on the playing field. The agent's task is to collect as many chicken legs as possible. I started my research with a genetic algorithm. I created a tensor flow model, in which I submitted the state of the game to the input. I didn't teach the model. In tensors, it's just a set of random weights. After each pass of the game, we choose the winners, cross them and mutate a little. The crossing and mutation itself occurs directly in the neural network that is attached to each agent. I do not teach the system, I take weights from the neural network (brain) of the agent and perform mutation and crossing directly, I change the coefficients in tensors. Result = 10 chicken legs. This is not bad, the agents are really trained, but I am not satisfied with the result. I now want to use reinforcement learning. I'm new to this field and I can't find examples anywhere of exactly how to praise or fine a neuron for wrong actions. It is in the form of a code. I understand the concept of the award, but how to implement it...I can't think without the order of actions. For example, the agent walked across the playing field 1 time. He made 4 moves to the left and went outside the playing field. On the 2nd move, he hit the cage with a chicken leg. The experiment is over. Every move, I saved the state of the game (the game environment for input neurons) to an array and saved the rewards to another array [0,1,0,-1] => 1 - reward for a chicken leg, -1 for going beyond.
How do I now teach the system with this data?

(I assumed that it was necessary to reduce the weights of y along the branch from the wrong output neuron to the incoming data by a gradient. Not training the neural network at all, but working purely with weights)

Comment: Not 100% sure what your trying to do here, if you alter the backprop based on output, then a NN will probably never converge.  It makes more sense to alter the expect output neurons to give the answer you require, fudging the error seems like a strange thing to do.

Comment: I am also not sure of the correctness of the solution I have chosen. I thought to reduce in detail the weights in the branch that leads to a bad action of the agent, so that he does not commit this action again. In this case, I would change the weights directly in the tensors, rather than retrain the system.

Comment: If the weights for single sample get altered, then the training you have already done becomes less accurate, unfortunately the way NN's work, the more data you have the more accurate it will be, so re-training on the updated dataset is the correct thing to do, but you shouldn't need to start from scratch, most NN's have the ability to save / load the weights, so the training shouldn't need to start from scratch again, just add the corrected result and re-train on the new extended dataset.

Comment: rewards and penalties are obviously not differentiable, thus you can't calculate "the error wrt some weights"... this means that you can't use backprop as it is. AFAIK, what you instead should look for, is the reinforce algorithm, which takes an expectation of the reward, making it differentiable

Answer (score 0):

Consider that RL agents do not learn from what is a good or bad action, but they do learn from rewards.

An action is never explicitly tagged as good or bad, just a reward is given back. and usually rewards comes as consequence of several actions.

Consider a simple agent that learns to play tic tac toe. Usually reward is 1 for winning, -1 when looses and 0 for ties. For any other action (i.e. intermediate actions while playing is going on) reward is 0.

Now the agent makes it first move: whatever it is, it will get 0 as reward. Was it a good or a bad move? You don't know until the end of the game. And more formally, you don't even know at the end: the agent may win a game even with a very bad initial movement.

This is also valid for any other action, not only the initial. To guess how good was an action in RL (and in any trial-error framework) is known as the credit assignment problem, and is not explicitly solved.

This is what makes RL very different from supervised learning: in supervised learning, you have pairs of inputs and expected outputs, that tell how to solve you task. In RL you just know **what to do** (win a tic tac toe game) but you don't know **how** to do it, so you just pay the agent once he does it ok.

That said, there are several formulations on how to solve an RL problem, from your question I assume you're trying to do Q-learning: the agent learns a function called Q which takes a state and an action and tell how good is the action for the state. When the function is modeled as a neural network, it usually takes as input a state and outputs the Q for each action: exactly as the model you share in the image.

And now we arrive to your question: how do you update the function? Well, first you need to take an action from your current state. Which to take? The best? Well, since your agent is learning, taking always the action he think is the best won't help: he will be wrong most of the time and will only try bad movements. A random one? This may help, but it is also problematic since randomly playing is hard to achieve the task and get paid, so it will not succeed and never learns. What I introduced here is the exploration-exploitation dilema: what to do, expoit agent's knowledge taking the action supposed to be the best or explore trying something different to guess what happens? You need to do both, and an appropriate balance among them is crucial. A simple, yet effective way to achieve this is the epsilon-greedy strategy: with a probability of epsilon take a greedy action (best up to agent's knowledge) otherwise take a random action (explore).

Once you take an action, you receive a reward, and it's time to learn from this reward and update your function. For this, you have your current Q function at time t and the brand-new reward, at time t, and want to update the Q function in time t+1.

There are some small details not covered here to make it work, just wanted to clarify some points. For a keras based implementation, take a look at [this](https://keras.io/examples/rl/deep_q_network_breakout/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You wrote quite correctly about reinforcement learning. I added "UPD" at the end of the question text with clarifications and a question for you.